# Associate custom categories to different user IDs

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, users

I am trying to associate custom categories created by different users to their userIDs.
I did that with custom posts and custom pages, but I really have no idea on how I can do that with the custom post type categories.

This because I want that each user logged in can add his own categories only and cannot see categories added by others.

Any help is really appreciated!

Best

Comment: You've got a big project and will need substantial code. Try looking through the source of similar plugins to see what you are in for, and hopefully get a start.

Comment: I am also opened to another way to achieve this. Something like metafields populated like category or something else!

Comment: I know, but you are looking at substantial code. As is, this looks like a "work for me for free" question. There are numerous bits of functionality that will need to be altered via numerous hooks. That is a lot to ask. Please try to get yourself started or I suspect this will be closed as "too broad".

Comment: I asked just to have a hint, nothing "be my slave" alike.
Just is there an easy way to achieve it as for the posts and pages? Yes/No. Using for example a mix of custom capabilities and force and user to read only things with his userID (as I did for posts and pages).

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, ideal solution would be this plugin: [Restrict Categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-categories/)

It allows you to restrict the users to **`add`**, **`view`** and **`edit`** categories.

**`Note:`** But before installing, make sure you have a backup. The most recent review had a problem of categories getting disappeared.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want to do that in my custom plugin. Moreover Restrict Categories is not compatible with latest Wordpress updates!